# Kendo Treeview Remote Binding c# variable inside template

Tags: c#, templates, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm using MVC *Razor* view and Kendo Controls

How do I keep a global variable that reside in my C# code block but at the same time, also available inside my Kendo Template so that I can incerement it for every items I fetch?

What I need is this:

**Kendo Treeview:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
  .Name("DatasourceTreeview")
  .DataTextField("ControlId")
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
  .Read(read => read
    .Action("RetrieveTreeviewItems", "Customizer")
    .Data("submitParams")).Events(e => e.RequestStart("loadParams")))
   .TemplateId("treeview-template")
  )
```

**Variable:**

```
@ { int globalVariable = 1; }
```

**Template:**

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">  
 # switch (item.ControlType) {
     case "control1": #
        globalVariable += 1;
     # break; #
     # case "control2": #
        globalVariable += 2;
     # break; #
     # default: #
        globalVariable += 3;
     # break; #
</script>
```

**Result:**
incremented *globalVariable*

After passing through the template and rendering the treeview, I would like to use the incremented globalVariable. But the C# variable itself is not visible inside the Template. How can I;

- Initialize a variable in C# code block then Pass it to the template
- Increment depending on the data retrieved
- Pass it back to C# code block

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a JavaScript variable because Kendo Templates are nothing else but JavaScript code. Here is how:

```
<script>
var globalVariable = @globalVariable;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your solution and I was able to use the value of the variable inside the script(javascript). But my problem is , how can I retrieve the value of the variable and use it outside the script (C#). Do you have an idea how can I acheive this?

Comment: If you want to use a JavaScript variable on the server side you need to post it in a hidden field. Then it would be accessible as a parameter of your action method.